# How do I show that the space $C([0,T), C^{k,\alpha}(B(t)))$ with norm $\sup_{t<T} \|f(x,t)\|_{k,\alpha,B(t)}$ is a Banach space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $C([0,T), C^{k,\alpha}(B(t)))$ be defined as the space of functions with respect to $(x,t) \in \{(x,t) : [0,T) \in B(t)\}$, with norm $\sup_{t<T} \|f(x,t)\|_{k,\alpha,B(t)}$ of finite value, is a Banach space. Here, $B(t)$ is a bounded domain for all $t \in [0,T)$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|_{k,\alpha,B}$ is the usual $C^{k,\alpha}$ (Holder) norm.

My question is, how do I show that is indeed a Banach space?

I think that the conclusion that the space in question is a Banach space is already immediate from the fact that the space of $C^{k,\alpha}(B(t)))$ is already a Banach space over bounded domains $B(t)$ for each $t \in [0, T)$. Is this right?

Comment: what is $C^\alpha (B(t))$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $C^{k,\alpha}(B(t))$ is the usual Holder space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition) over $B(t)$.